# Recorded & uploaded video from iphone device won't play in iphone

Tags: php, ios, wordpress, ffmpeg

I am facing an issue regarding :

> Recording video from iphone and uploading that video on my application(Develop in Wordpress Framework)  then the video uploaded won't play in iphone devices.

This issue occurs only when I "Record video from iphone and then uploading that video into the application".If I upload existing video from iphone device then video will be played and it's working fine. So please help to resolve this issue.I have used "FFmpeg library" to reduce the size of video.

Below is the code which i have used to play video :

```
<video preload="auto" width="320" height="240" controls=""><source src="abc.mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
```

When i click on video to play it then video is not play and cross sign is shown over the play button.Below i have attached screenshot of it :
[image]

Comment: First you say the video directly from the iphone doesn't work. Then you say it does work. Then you say you are using ffmpeg. Confusing. So what's happening here? How was `abc.mp4` created?

Comment: The process which i have done for uploading video is used "ffmpeg library" in which i have reduce the size of video and also rename the video and change the extension of video i.e. ".mp4".Here above "abc.mp4" i have used as an example because i can't disclose the whole path of video.And now the issue is when i record video from iphone and after recording i upload it to the website then video is uploaded successfully but after uploading the video then that video which is stored on server won't play in iphone. @llogan

Comment: So the process is: Record video on iPhone > Re-encode with ffmpeg > Upload to server > View on iPhone? Show your ffmpeg command and the complete log.

Comment: The code is lengthy. So from which medium I can send the code to you?

Comment: You can use a pastebin site and provide the link in a comment or just [edit] your question and include it.